# Estimate bounds on Minkowski distance from point to a segment in Lp space

Tags: linear-algebra, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities, norms, metric-spaces

### Assumptions

Let

$L_p(x,y)=(\sum_i|x_i - y_i|^p)^{1/p}$ (Minkowski metric),

$a,b$ be arbitrary $n$-dimensional points,

$c$ be a point that satisfies  $L_p(a,b) = L_p(a,c) + L_p(c,b)$, i.e., a point in $L_p$-metric segment between $a$ and $b$,

$t$ be another point (possibly outside the segment).

$1 \leq p \leq \infty$

$1 \leq q \leq \infty$

$L_q(a,t)$, $L_q(b,t)$, $L_p(a,b)$ are known and finite.

### The question

I'd like to estimate (tight) bounds on distance $L_q(c,t)$, preferably without referring to $a,b,c,t$ as points/vectors, instead using metrics only, however if this is necessary I'll accept that.

Are there any suggestions how to solve the above problem?

### Alternative question

Alternatively to the above, it would be enough to me to show that $L_q(c,t) \leq \max\{L_q(a,t), L_q(b,t)\}$.

Note, it is easy to show that the above condition is false for $1 \leq p < q \leq \infty$, given e.g., $p=1, q=2$ (draw it in 2D). However how to prove this for $1 \leq q \leq p \leq \infty$ or designate other bounds on $p$ and $q$ for which the condition is true?

**Possible hint**

For $q \leq p$ the following is true ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/218046/68706)):

$L_p(x,y) \leq L_q(x,y) \leq n^{1/q - 1/p} L_p(x,y)$

where $n$ is dimensionality of $L_p$ space.

Related question on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1049806/68706).

Comment: Are you looking for bounds from both directions or only from above? What do you need the estimate for, if I may ask? Your question is very specific but you give no motivation for it.

Comment: Upper bound on $L_q(c,t)$ would be enough. Possibly if I knew how to estimate that, I would also estimate the lower bound, however it's a minor thing. I try to estimate worst-case scenario for an algorithm that I'm working on.

Comment: How is this question different from the question on Math.StackExchange? Please wait a few days before reposting the question on MathOverflow, or ask the moderators to migrate it here.